# pandas DataFrame booler

Tags: pandas, dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,6), columns=list('abcdef'))
    
df[df.loc[0] > 1]
```

> ---
>
> IndexingError                             Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> 1 df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,6), columns=list('abcdef'))
> 2
> ----> 3 df[df.loc[0] > 1]
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in
> **getitem**(self, key)    2891         # Do we have a (boolean) 1d indexer?    2892         if com.is_bool_indexer(key):
> -> 2893             return self._getitem_bool_array(key)    2894     2895         # We are left with two options: a single key, and a
> collection of keys,
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in
> _getitem_bool_array(self, key)    2943         # check_bool_indexer will throw exception if Series key cannot    2944         # be
> reindexed to match DataFrame rows
> -> 2945         key = check_bool_indexer(self.index, key)    2946         indexer = key.nonzero()[0]    2947         return
> self._take_with_is_copy(indexer, axis=0)
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in
> check_bool_indexer(index, key)    2182         mask =
> isna(result._values)    2183         if mask.any():
> -> 2184             raise IndexingError(    2185                 "Unalignable boolean Series provided as "    2186
> "indexer (index of the boolean Series and of "
>
> IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index
> of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).

and I try

```
df(pd.DataFrame(df.loc[0] > 1).T)
```

> ---
>
> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> 1 df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,6), columns=list('abcdef'))
> 2
> ----> 3 df(pd.DataFrame(df.loc[0] > 1).T)
>
> TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable

what should I do ? Thanks.

Comment: you can review the .loc syntax in the official documentation or google "how to use .loc Stackoverflow pandas"  Try the following: `df.loc[df[0] > 1]` or `df[df[0] > 1]`

Comment: df[0] > 1 means 1st column, df.loc[0] means 1st row.